# Window function with sum returns excessively large number

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm confused about why a simple sum window function is returning the below output, note the "running total" value:

[image]

My query is:

```
select month,
       "total sales", 
       sum("total sales") over (order by "month number" asc) as "running total"
from
(
    select to_char(date, 'Month') as month,
           sum(sale_price) as "total sales",
           extract(MONTH from date) as "month number"
    from sales
    group by month, "month number"
) as sub_sales
order by "month number" asc;
```

My input data is the following:

[image]

I would expect this to work out such that the "running total" column returns a cumulative sum of sale_price.

Comment: Please don't post unreadable [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It seems like converting the date to a string `to_char(date, 'Month') as month` before relying on the sort order of them may be problematic.

Comment: Does Postgresql really let you GROUP BY column aliases?

Comment: @jarlh looks to [be the case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f84178564e424b2e25885f52938d387e)!

Comment: @Stu, thank you for the somewhat surprising information.

Comment: 1) The window function is over `"total sales"` not `sale_price`. 2) The running total is a cumulative sum `0.259e3 = 259, 0.589e3 = 598(259 +339), 0.902e3 = 902(598+304)`and so on.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver why are the numbers decimals and in scientific notation? In other window sums, this doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm guessing it is being done by whatever client you are using. Try the query in `psql` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue, based on @AdrianKlaver comment:

```
select month,
       "total sales", 
       sum("total sales") over (order by "month number" asc)::int as "running total"
from
(
    select to_char(date, 'Month') as month,
           sum(sale_price) as "total sales",
           extract(MONTH from date) as "month number"
    from sales
    group by month, "month number"
) as sub_sales
order by "month number" asc;
```

Not sure why the running total would be formatted that way, though?